# How to fix mkdir() "Read-only file system" on shared hosting?

Tags: php, file-permissions, shared-hosting, mkdir

I'm trying to set up functionality which allows a user to upload files to a directory on a server (shared hosting). The user can type in an upload folder name and select files. If the folder doesn't exist, it gets created.

Please note that this is no big upload system, but for only one user.

My code works fine on `localhost`. 
With the public server (shared hosting), creating the folder works. But no files show up in it.

**Upload function, `process.php`:**

```
// run code only if post request went through
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {

    if (isset($_POST['folder'])) {
        $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    } else {
        $folder = 'new-folder';
    }

    // ensure that there are files inside the array to actually upload
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

        $errors = [];
        $path = '/dir/data/uploads/images/' . $folder . "/";

        // if folder does not exist, create it
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        } else {
            //stuff
        }

        $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
            $file_ext = strtolower(end($tmp));

            $file = $path . $file_name;

            // here follow multiple verifications on the file name, type, size, etc...
            // removed to keep code shorter

            if (empty($errors)) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
            }
        }

        if ($errors) print_r($errors);
    } 
}
```

**Attempts and observations:**

- In the network tab, I get `status code 200`.
- Read-write-execute permissions for the target folder `images` on the server are (temporarily, for testing!) set to `777`, `(rwxrwxrwx)`.
- I tested different files and different folder names (new and existing), but the files I try to upload never show up.
- I noticed that despite using `mkdir($path, 0777, true);` in my code to create the folder, the folder on the server has then permissions set to `705`, `(rwx---r-x)`.
- The only changes I made to this code from the version that runs just fine on `localhost` is that I changed `$path`.

**Error message I'm getting:**

```
Warning: mkdir(): Read-only file system in /path/to/scripts/process/process.php on line 31
/folder/data/uploads/images/test/image.webp -- 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/folder/data/uploads/images/test/image.webp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/scripts/process/process.php on line 75
```

And accordingly:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move (...)
```

- Line 31 is `mkdir($path, 0777, true);`
- Line 75 is `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);`

**I found several fixes for Linux file systems for this issue. But how can I go about this when using shared hosting?**

This is my first time attempting this and help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect via ssh? You most likely need to make a folder for the public uploads and asign the public group your host allows for web users (often www or www-data) write permissions to that folder recursively. Something like chown -R www-data:www-data images

Comment: I think they offer ssh only for cloud hosting. But I may be wrong. I've never used ssh. I can look into it. As is, I can change read-write-execute permissions for the folders on my webspace. But even when I allow everyone to read and write files, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the dir /dir/data/uploads/images/ within your public web root? I'm taking a guess but public user groups will only be allowed to upload to a public folder.  One other thing I just noticed: Your image has the extension .webp which your host may not have allowed. Did you try uploading a jpg?

Comment: It should be in the public web root, yeah. The error is the same for jpg. I have, however, a JavaScript preload function for images in my header that returns status code `403 forbidden` to me. There are also two .htaccess files (one in the data folder, one in uploads). I didn't write them or put them there, and I am not sure about this, but maybe the issue could be related to one of these .htaccess files? It only occurred to me now. I will look into them, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and tried around some more. This works:

```
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/data/uploads/images/' . $folder . "/";
```

I can now upload files into this folder.

Thanks for the help! I will definitely look into the things you suggested (and adjust access rights), as `PHP` is still not my strong suit. :)